# JavaScript Jquery stoping each function, blocked buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I try to do email sender with jQuery and I want to start and break sending by click button.

```
var arr;

function loadArray(table){ arr = table.data;}
function init(){
    $('#start').click(function(){
        $.each(arr, function( key, value ){   
            if(value !== null){
                var emailTemplate = value['emailTemplate'];
                var email = value['email'];
                var campaign = value['campaign'];
                sendAnEmail(emailTemplate, email, campaign, key);
                arr[key] = null;
            }
            console.log(arr);
            $(this).click(function(){
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
}
function sendAnEmail(template, email, campaign, num){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: { template: template, email: email, num: num, campaign: campaign },
        url: Routing.generate('wyslij_email'),
        success: function(msg){             
            if(msg.status == 'success'){
                var count = parseInt($('.sended').text());
                $('.sended').text(count+1);
            }else{
                var count = parseInt($('.error').text());
                $('.error').text(count+1);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I created simple function init, it work fine. After click #start it start each function. When each function loop I can't click any button.

I thing that AJAX block it by async = false; Is it true?

My question is simple. Why it doesn't work?

Comment: You're using `async: false`. *Never* use async false - it blocks the UI thread from updating. I would also remove the nested click handler on the `#start` element.

Comment: `Routing.generate('wyslij_email')` - what's that ?

Comment: @northkildonan not part of the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use `async: false`, whis will block the script!

if you need them to be sent after each other, you could build up a stack with the loop and then send them after each other (for example...):

```
//outside function context (global variable)
var stack = [];

//in loop, instead of calling the function
stack.push({template: template, email: email, num: num, campaign: campaign});

//after loop:
stack.reverse(); //if you need them to be in the order they got created....if not, just erase this line
sendData();

function sendData(){
   if(stack.length > 0){
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "json",
         data:stack.pop(), //get next entry
         async:true, //or delete this line, since true is default
         url: Routing.generate('wyslij_email'),
         success:function(msg){
             if(msg.status == 'success'){
                var count = parseInt($('.sended').text());
                $('.sended').text(count+1);
                sendData(); //recurse to next stack item
             } else {
                var count = parseInt($('.error').text());
                $('.error').text(count+1);
             }
         }
      });
   }

}
```